# Remote desktop to main session

Tags: linux, xorg, rdp

I need help with `xrdp`; I need a remote desktop to the same "X server" the Pi boots into. Is this possible?  E.g., if:

- I have the Pi with keyboard but no display and I want see input through remote desktop.
- I have the Pi connected to my TV and I want control it via RDP from my computer.

I know how to setup `xrdp` and VNC but all of them start a new session for each connection. I need something like Teamviewer.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=38922 might get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing x11vnc daemon on the raspberry pi. 
Then run the command :

```
x11vnc -display :0 -usepw -noxdamage -ncache 10 -ncache_cr
```

Then you'll be able to connect to the active session from your computer.